# How trunc multiline text in css-grid

Tags: html, css, truncate, css-grid

I'm trying to trunc multiline text in css grid. I have problem that it truncs half line (in vertical and depends on screen size) and other half still visible. I want that visible be only whole letters. So far my code below. In other questions I found solution only for trunc one line text. Also code below. How I can do this?

[image]

```
.className {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #eee;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 4fr;
  grid-template-columns: 4fr 1fr;
}

.title {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1 / 3
}

.image {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 3
}

.desc {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">Hello World</div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c841026/v841026173/4efd9/Rte5_pRqCAg.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="desc">
    Hello in my little world. 
    Hello in my little world.
    Hello in my little world. 
    Hello in my little world.
    Hello in my little world. 
    Hello in my little world.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what output r u expecting?

Comment: @Maddyplusplus, updated question

Comment: add a small padding-top to hide the half of the text

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/

Comment: @TemaniAfif, in different content I should every time update it

Comment: if the font-size, line-height is always the same you don't have to change it

Comment: @TemaniAfif, ((, I use adaptive typography